# Differences between vector, set, and tuple

Tags: language-agnostic, vector, tuples, set

What are the differences between vectors, sets, and tuples in programming?

Comment: You have your answer, but as an additional point, in mathematics a set can also be infinite, for example the set `{1,2,3,...}` or the set of real numbers.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

- Vector: Ordered collection of objects of the same type.
- Set: Unordered collection of objects, possibly of the same type or possibly different depending on the collection type and language.  Any given object can only appear once.
- Tuple: Ordered collection of objects of different types.

Comment: I haven't seen a definition of a vector before that restricts to a single type... interested, can you point me at a resource?

Comment: @Brabster: std::vector in C++ is an example.

Comment: Oh, I see thanks. Possibly some languages do constrain type for their Vector implementation and others do not (example Java, can take any Object in it's Vector implementation). I hadn't noticed that before.

Comment: I think that since these terms cross the line into the proof-filled math side of CS, the definition is not necessarily going to be what your co-workers are using the word for.

Comment: I disagree with Brabster's assertion that Java doesn't constrain types on Vectors.  std::vector also doesn't constrain types either from that thinking, since you can always have a vector of unconstrained pointers. In Java, a Vector contains Object Types. It is not unconstrained.

Comment: describing a tuple like an ordered collection is not quite accurate, because a tuple represents a compound value, and not a collection of less related values. like a 3d vector that represents a position in space [x,y,z] vs a list o 3 numbers that represent the distance in time from one location to another in a UPS route.

Comment: in some untyped languages you have both tuples and lists, in which case i would define a tuple like a struct with nameless positional attributes, and a vector as an ordered collection of values. And both are optimized for those cases, a tuple is contiguos in memory while a vector has different implementation to support resizing, a tuple is not meant to be resized

Comment: The elements of a tuple are not necessarily of different types.

Answer (score 21):

A `vector` is an ordered sequence of items that does allow duplicates.

A `set` is a collection of items that is unordered and does not allow duplicates.

A `tuple` is an ordered sequence of items of a given length.

Answer (score 8):

Mathematically

> A tuple has properties that distinguish it from a set.
>
> - A tuple may contain multiple instances of the same element, so tuple    (1,2,2,3) != (1,2,3) but set {1,2,2,3} = {1,2,3}.
> - Tuple elements are ordered: tuple (1,2,3) != (3,2,1), but set {1,2,3} = {3,2,1}.
> - A tuple has a finite number of elements, while a set or a multiset    may have an infinite number of elements.

Vector is a different type represented by multiple tuples.

Cheers :-)

Answer (score 6):

A tuple is a heterogeneous collection of objects, which should be treated as a single unit: for example, ("John", "Smith", 30) is a (String, String, Integer) tuple.

A list (in C++: and also vector) is a homogeneous collection of objects -- that is, each object can be treated uniformly. Whether they are actually the same type depends on the language, but the point is that they can be processed the same way.

A set is an unordered unique homogenous collection -- you know what objects it contains, and what type they are, but not in what order, and it only contains one of each object.

Comment: double would be the 2 element tuple (2-tuple), although that term (usually) has a different meaning in the context of computers.

Comment: list and vector are distinct concepts in C++.  Although they both represent ordered, homogeneous collections, list implies O(1) inserts and vector implies O(1) seek, that is list is implemented as some sort of linked list structure, and vector is implemented as an array.

Comment: Token: thanks for the list/vector duality, I've clarified that in C++ the vector is an additional type.

Answer (score 3):

Vectors have an ordering

Tuples are ordered and can have repeat elements.

Sets are unordered and repeat elements do not change the set.

For example: {a,b}, {b,a}, and {b,b,a} are all the same set, while (a,b), (b,a) and (b,b,a) are all different tuples.

Answer (score 2):

the difference is *tuples* are not meant to be treated as collections, while vectors & sets are.

- *tuples* are meant to represent *compound values*, like position in a 3d space with (x,y,z) coordinates, it doesn't make sense to see it as
  a collection, because yes is a list of 3 numbers but the 3 numbers
  have different meaning and combined form an specific meaning.

  Think of *tuples* as a structs with nameless positional attributes
  that can have different types. As such is not meant to store lots of
  values, and this is why all implementations of these things are
  optimized for a small number of them

  an example of *tuple* is the type used to describe the columns of a
  single row in a SQL Database, in fact that is what rows are called in
  Relational Algebra.
- A *Vector* (terrible name by the way, because the word in math is used for compound values not for collections) is an ordered collection that
  is meant to store lots of values, it is usually implemented to grow as
  needed keeping an access of O(1)

  a table in a SQL DB without primary key would be a Vector of tuples.
- A *Set* is a collection of unique elements, that can be ordered but it doesn't have to be.

  a table in a SQL DB with primary key would be Set of tuples.

Comment: nice clarification of `tuples`

Answer (score 0):

Vectors have an ordering, sets do not (and can't have duplicates), and tuples are close to vectors but are usually used more like structs in practice.